# ckeditor not loading in Flask application

Tags: javascript, python, flask, ckeditor

So I'm using pycharm to build a simple web app. Trying to use ckeditor to make parts of certain forms customisable. first of all, here is the full directory structure

```
<Root>
  -<app>
    -<templates>
    __init__.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    routes.py
-<migrations>
-<static>
    -<ckeditor>
      {ckeditor directories bla etc bla}
      ckeditor.js
app.db
config.py
application.py
```

In my base template I have the following code

```
{% block scripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I run the application the toolbar for ckeditor does not show. Strangely enough the CKEditorField from the form (which I am using th editor for) appears as a textarea and the relevant js appears above it when I inspect. However console logs a 404 error

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/ckeditor/ckeditor.js 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

If I relocate the js file outside of its normal directory and place it directly in the templates directory of the app, after updating the correct path I get the following error

```
net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Comment: If you load `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` in your web-browser-- do you see the js code appear?

Comment: No it tells me not found

Comment: If you place a `hello.txt` file in your `static` folder, does `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/hello.txt` work?  If yes-- then you've got a typo, and the `ckeditor` file isn't where you expect.  If no-- then have you adjusted your flask code to believe that the `static` folder is actually elsewhere.

Comment: Doobeh++ Seems the static folder was outside the application scope. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Doobeh, the static directory was outside the application scope for some reason. Moved it under the app directory and now working